# angular tutorial not working on fiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been reading the angularjs tutorials on tutorialspoint.com and I've been testing things that I learn on jsfiddle. The first few things I tried worked, like `ng-model` and `ng-bind`. But this was all with an empty `ng-app` (`ng-app=""`).

However, now I'm trying to make an app and a controller, but its not working. [Heres the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLsbmfb7/)

How do I fix this code? I've done exactly as the tutorial says. I just noticed when inspecting the page I get the following error:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myapp due to:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'myapp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="appController">
    <div>
        <span>First</span>
        <input type='text' ng-model="person.firstname"/>
        <span ng-bind="person.firstname"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Last</span>
        <input type='text' ng-model="person.lastname"/>
        <span ng-bind="person.lastname"></span>
    </div>
    <div> {{ person.fullname() }} </div>
</div>

var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);
myapp.controller('appController', function($scope) {
    $scope.person = {
        firstname: "one",
        lastname: "two",
        fullname: function() {
            var personobject;
            personobject = $scope.person;
            return personobject.firstname + " " + personobject.lastname;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the **Frameworks and Settings** change the thing that says **onLoad** to **no wrap - in `<head>`** or **no wrap - in `<body>`**

[image]

Comment: I had a feeling it was something retarded like that.. thanks you're a life saver!